# JavaFx: Define operating system at build time

Tags: java, javafx

I have a java 11 project where i use javafx. I dont want anyone who uses my program to install javafx, so i wrote a main class that refers to the javafx main class (see code below). So i can start the jar with "java -jar myJar.jar" and it runs everywhere without the need to install javafx. The javafx modules are defined in the module-info.java.
Now i have the problem that my jar contains system depending libraries of javafx. I build on a linux system, so i have .so-files. Some of my customer use a windows system. So it doesnt run on their system. Is their a way to define (in maven or in java) the destination operating system? So that i can build a jar for windows?
Or Perhpas there is another, better way to solve my problem.
Thanks!

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B.main(args);
    }
}

public class B extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(B.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to go today is to package your JavaFX applications with `jpackage`. Have a look at its documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
At the link the following is stated:
"Application packages must be built on the target platform. The system used for packaging must contain the application, a JDK, and software needed by the packaging tool.

To package your application for multiple platforms, you must run the packaging tool on each platform. If you want more than one format for a platform, you must run the tool once for each format."

So i still need to build it on a windows system. Its the same situation i have at the moment.

Comment: Yes, because for all OSes I know the native tools you need (like wix on Windows) are only available on these platforms. If you are looking for a possibility to build for all platforms without owning them, you could use GitHub Actions for example. There is documentation available on how to do that with JavaFX. But somehow you will have to test your builds on all platforms anyway. Or do you leave that to the user ?